# using custom filter in angular js 1.6.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

The below snippet was working perfectly with angular 1.4.2, however after upgrading the angular js library to 1.6.2.

I have searched the migration/upgrading docs..etc. Not found a solution.

HTML code:

```
<input ng-model="query" type="text" name="js_filter" >
```

part of my custom table, `tbItems.rows` would contain some data in an array/object format

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="datarow in resultItems = (tbItems.rows | filter:magikFilterQuery ) " >
```

javascript snippet:

```
myControllers.controller('myContrBasic', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.magikFilterQuery = function (item) {
        var term;
        var part;
        if (angular.isUndefined($scope.query) === false) {
          if ($scope.matchcase === true) {
            term = item.data[3];
            part = $scope.query;
          }
          else {
            term = angular.lowercase(item.data[3]);
            part = angular.lowercase($scope.query);
          }
          if (term.indexOf(part) === -1) {
            return false;
          }
          else {
            return true;
          }
        }
        else {
          return true;
        }
      };
```

Error after upgrading angular js:

```
angular.js:14362 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/$injector/unpr?p0=magikFilterQueryFilterProvider%20%3C-%20magikFilterQueryFilter
    at http://localhost/site82/folder/js/angular162/angular.min.js?v=8.2.6:6:425
    at http://localhost/site82/folder/js/angular162/angular.min.js?v=8.2.6:44:374
    at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost/site82/folder/js/angular162/angular.min.js?v=8.2.6:42:92)
    at http://localhost/site82/folder/js/angular162/angular.min.js?v=8.2.6:44:436
    at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost/site82/folder/js/angular162/angular.min.js?v=8.2.6:42:92)
    at http://localhost/site82/folder/js/angular162/angular.min.js?v=8.2.6:163:474
    at U (http://localhost/site82/folder/js/angular162/angular.min.js?v=8.2.6:125:13)
    at http://localhost/site82/folder/js/angular162/angular.min.js?v=8.2.6:123:123
    at q (http://localhost/site82/folder/js/angular162/angular.min.js?v=8.2.6:7:351)
    at U (http://localhost/site82/folder/js/angular162/angular.min.js?v=8.2.6:123:102) <!-- ngRepeat: datarow in  (tbItems.rows | magikFilterQuery ) as resultItems -->
```

Comment: please inject $filter in controller and then try

Comment: no luck, getting same error

Comment: Alternatively i have seen the `.filter()` function being used on some sites.. can i use that... in this case

Comment: myControllers.controller('myContrBasic', ['$scope','$filter', '$http',
    function ($scope, $filter,$http) { }    Do you inject like this?

Comment: yes, `myControllers.controller('myContrBasic', ['$scope', '$http','$filter',
        function ($scope, $http, $filter) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to defined a filter for your function magikFilterQuery like

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('magikFilterQuery', function() {
  return function(item) {
    var term;
    var part;
    if (angular.isUndefined($scope.query) === false) {
      if ($scope.matchcase === true) {
        term = item.data[3];
        part = $scope.query;
      }
      else {
        term = angular.lowercase(item.data[3]);
        part = angular.lowercase($scope.query);
      }
      if (term.indexOf(part) === -1) {
        return false;
      }
      else {
        return true;
      }
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: using this am getting the entire object in `item` , will i have to re-iterate through it again

Comment: ok, i figured out a solution, I have edited the code snippet above.